# IMPDP from Oracle 10g TO 11g

Tags: oracle, impdp, expdp

I'm not able to import the full database from oracle 10g to 11g using `impdp FULL=Y`. It seems that the file path is differing so what shall I do?
The `impdp` command is looking for oracle 10g path while importing into 11g db.
is there any way to import full database from 10g to 11g using `impdp`?

Comment: Please paste the commands you are using in your operating system and the error you are getting

Comment: Which version of impdp are you using?

Comment: What is the exact error message you are receiving? Sometimes it can be the tablespace path that is causing issues and sometimes it's just the EXPORT directory defined in the Oracle instance that can cause issues.

Comment: Exactly what "file path is differing" are you talking about?  If the path for the files to be created as part of TS creation, then @Balazs Papp has provided the answer.  But if you mean the path to the impdp executable, then that is simply a matter of having the correct directory listed first in the PATH variable of your unknown OS.

Comment: The issue was with the table space.. when it try to create users it cant be able to find the path associated with the table space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full export/import contains tablespace definitions with datafile paths as well, so `impdp` tries to create the datafiles with the original path.

Just create the tablespaces manually before running impdp, that is usually what I do. `impdp` will notice that the tablespaces already exist, and continue with the remaining objects.

You can extract the tablespace creation scripts as well if you want, using the `sqlfile` clause:

```
impdp user/password directory=... dumpfile=... sqlfile=ts.sql include=TABLESPACE
```

The above creates a `ts.sql` file containing the `CREATE` and `ALTER` statements for your tablespaces, which you can edit or use for creating the tablespaces.